# Multi-page UITableViewController with animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I'm currently running an app that shows a `UITableViewController`, with data dynamically loaded into it. On the navigation bar, i have a "previous" and "next" button, that loads new data in the current view controller. It works really well.

What i want i taking it to the next level : i'd like to be able to detect left and right swipe gestures in order to show animated transitions with next / previous pages. 
For instance, when i swipe right i'd like to have a transition showing a new `UITableViewController`, with the correct data that would be loaded in the background. Something like a `PageViewController`, but with infinite number of pages.

Is there a trivial way to do this? Or do i have to go with `GesturesDetecror` and custom transitions ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Gesture recognizers are implemented for this purpose. There is a class specifically for swiping left and swiping right, which is what I think you're looking for.

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to implement swipes in order to replace what the current next and previous buttons are doing, plus some swiping animation to transition between tables of data. The swipe detection can be accomplished by simply adding the appropriate gesture recognizers to the table view. The appropriate gesture recognizer here is the UISwipeGestureRecognizer class.

This can be done programmatically (probably in the viewDidLoad of the VC). First, create a UISwipeGestureRecognizer:

```
var swipeRight: UIGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipeRight")
```

Default direction for a gesture recognizer is right, so theres no need to set the swipes direction. The direction is stored in the gesture recognizers direction property. Now add the gesture recognizer to the tableview:

```
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

After this setup these two lines of code the view controller is set up to call the function didSwipeRight any time a swipe right gesture is detected.

```
func didSwipeRight() {

    // Code to go to previous page

}
```

Then do the same for the swipe left, only you have to include a line to set the direction to be left.

```
var swipeLeft: UIGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipeLeft")
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

And then the function to handle the left swipes...

```
func didSwipeLeft() {

    //Code to go to next page.

}
```

And then implement the transitions within the body of their corresponding functions. Since you are wanting an infinite number of pages, I think the solution is to create a single view controller configured to show a transition with every swipe, but in reality it is only a single view controller. Hope that helps.